# Windows Forms PropertyView invisible texts

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, .net-5

I have a popup in C# solution that has a PropertyView control in it... All of a sudden the property fields are reporting an invisible value but if I click in the field the value becomes visible. If I then click out of that field the value hides itself again...
Yesterday it was all fine today I updated to visual studio 16.9.1 from 16.9.0... Can that be the cause???
Also on the deplyed solution on another computer these fields behave in the same way... but yesterday on my station it was all fine and I didn't touch those popups in at least a week...
The code is in c# developed in .Net 5 with windows forms.

```
namespace LiMA.Manager
{
    partial class PlcParametersPopup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.plcPropertyGrid = new System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid();
            this.setPlcParamsBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // plcPropertyGrid
            // 
            this.plcPropertyGrid.CommandsBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
            this.plcPropertyGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 2);
            this.plcPropertyGrid.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.plcPropertyGrid.Name = "plcPropertyGrid";
            this.plcPropertyGrid.PropertySort = System.Windows.Forms.PropertySort.Categorized;
            this.plcPropertyGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(379, 710);
            this.plcPropertyGrid.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // setPlcParamsBtn
            // 
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(50)))));
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 718);
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Name = "setPlcParamsBtn";
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(379, 40);
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.TabIndex = 1;
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Text = "Set PLC Parameters";
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.setPlcParamsBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.setPlcParamsBtn_Click);
            // 
            // PlcParametersPopup
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(15)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(384, 761);
            this.Controls.Add(this.setPlcParamsBtn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.plcPropertyGrid);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.Name = "PlcParametersPopup";
            this.Text = "<PlcName> Parameters";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid plcPropertyGrid;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button setPlcParamsBtn;
    }
}
```

This is my popup designer class.

```
public PlcParametersPopup(PlcSettings plcParameters, MainView main)
{
       InitializeComponent();

       PlcName = plcParameters.Name;

       Text = PlcName + " Parameters";

       plcPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = plcParameters;
       mainView = main;
}
```

This is the constructor of the popup and as you can see I pass to the SelectedObject field my class that contains a series of property fields as follows.

```
namespace LiMA.Parameters
{
    public class PlcSettings
    {
        [Category("Basic Settings"), Description("Name of the PLC"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Category("Addressing Settings"), Description("Ip address of the PLC"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public string IpAddr { get; set; }

        [Category("Addressing Settings"), Description("PLC rack from hw configuration"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int Rack { get; set; }

        [Category("Addressing Settings"), Description("PLC slot from hw configuration"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int Slot { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Datablock number in the PLC"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int DBNumber { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteWatchdogToPLC { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteStringMessage { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteCommands { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteAlarms { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteWarnings { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteOutParams { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteInParams { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteDataProcessor1 { get; set; }

        [Category("Data Settings"), Description("Byte offset in datablock"), ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ByteDataProcessor2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: there we go added a lot of parts of code which I don't think are necessary though... as I said yesterday it was working :(